# Numerical level of the second player

Tags: rocket-league

Say I am a *Veteran* and my split-screen player is *Pro* (since he earns his own experience points). I know that from the garage, where I can show or hide the level.

Is there a way to find out which numerical level the split-screen player has, so that I know how soon he'll advance to the next level?

I can't find it in Extras/Statistics either.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but the question about split screen XP you linked is for Modern Warfare 3. I never played the split-screen in Rocket League, but maybe this helps: https://steamcommunity.com/app/252950/discussions/0/490123938431972956/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this Steam forum post](https://steamcommunity.com/app/252950/discussions/0/490123938431972956/) you can watch the level and progress of a second split-screen player by having the second player open the menu during a match. The level and progress bar will appear on the screen, as can be seen in the screenshot:

[image: Rocket League Second Player Stats]